# MS Word or Latex for Thesis for beginner in LaTex

Tags: thesis, msword, latex-misc

I am writing my thesis in MS Word but one of my friend told me about writing thesis in LaTex instead of using MS word. But I have no idea about LaTex. I just want to know is LaTex worth for learning for writing thesis as there is trade-off between time devoted to learn LaTex and  time saved.

Please suggest me, is it beneficial for beginner to learn LaTex and write his/her thesis in LaTex instead of using MS word ?

Comment: It depends a bit on the scientific field how large the benefit is. Esp. do you have a lot of maths involved, do you need a lot of citations, do you need a lot of figures, tables, what kind of figures, etc. For a graphics designer, I would hardly recommend LaTeX for the thesis, but in most other cases I probably would. Please give us some details.

Comment: @Chris thanks..I am finance student. Yes, my work  involve lot of citation, figures and tables. Tables are created in excel. I need to put caption and title in figures and tables, also required to type equations but not so many[hardly 100].

Comment: I also want to know if I change chapter number in future, does LaTex change equation number, caption, section number etc automatically or do they require manual editing ?

Comment: Automatically, of course :)

Comment: @MWijnand It means making changing in LaTex is more easier than MS word. I have content but some chapter sections are not define right now. It means I can type in LaTex and make changes appropriately later without making changes in equation no., table no, etc.

Comment: This question surely will be closed as opinion-based. Old users of this site are fanatics of LaTeX but there are also [people that simply hate LaTeX](http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~aty/bibliog/latex/gripe.html). No matter of how wrong they are for us, we can not guess of what group you are. Are you an expert in Word? Do you prefer programming in plain text or a  GUI?  However, my suggestion: Try it. A good starting point could be download LyX but also learn how to make basics documents without LyX to well-understand what is under the GUI.

Comment: @Neeraj: Word too can do automatic numbering. You only need to use it correctly.

Comment: Almost everything can be reliably automated. In fact, that's the default behaviour for section numbering, equation numbers, caption numbers (and caption positioning), references handling and so on. I would suggest that you invest some time to try out LaTeX for your purpose. What you will need is a good beginners introduction, and maybe your friend can help you to have a good start with it. But if you are observing that it does not fit your style of working, then do not use it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes it can. But. I'm writing my 4th funding proposal this year with Word (2013), all of them being less than 20 pages, and it is always a mess. E.g., yesterday, I inserted 4 figures sequentially (one after each other and one below each other) and gave them captions. After the 4th, the order of the captions was changed to 4-2-3-1. This order changes with every new start of the program, randomly. These things are so annoying! Nevertheless, as you can see from my other comment, I am not fanatic about TeX. For the OP it would be best to chose the software that serves him best.

Comment: @Chris: I'm a latex fanatic too (and loath word's list handling), but one shouldn't use it for the wrong reasons and one shouldn't underestimate the time needed to learn it. The worst latex users are the one who use it only reluctantly without real conviction. They should better fight a bit with word then a lot with latex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That's what I tried to say :-)

Comment: Thanks to all for providing quick response. I think, I must go for some further research about utility of LaTex.